# Is there any way to pass some variables through ResourceController to template in Sylius?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I need to override behavior of `sylius_partial_product_latest` route to have ability render template with additional parameter.

The simple example: at the different pages I need to show from 2 to 4 products at a time with carousel scrolling through 4-8 products. Now in the `SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:latest` template I have:

```
{{ grid(products) }}
```

But I need in some cases:

```
{{ grid(products, 2) }}
```

In others:

```
{{ grid(products, 3) }}
{# or it can be 4 or any other number #}
```

Now in template I have only `products` var (it served by Resources mechanism), I can pass variables to the repository where I can add it to my `products` array, but it is not a good way. It can be accomplished by simple passing variables to the query:

```
{{ render(url('sylius_partial_product_latest', {'size': 3, 'limit': 2, 'template': 'SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:latest.html.twig'})) }}
```

I need to have ability to pass variable `size` to template `SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:latest` outside of `products`.

I tried override the `ProductBundle` and `ResourceBundle`... But overriding controllers with custom action (I do not want to override `indexAction` or `showAction`) led me nowhere. PHP doesn't hit my controller at all. Instead it hit `showAction` of `ResourceBundle`. And, yes, I overrode routing to point my controller.

If I override `ProductController` with new route and use it in my template it throws exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Controller "sylius.controller.product:partialAction" for URI
>   "/partial" is not callable.") in
>   SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:show.html.twig at line 136.

When I change `_controller` to point my controller in standard Symfony manner I have next exception:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\Configuration, none given,
>   called in
>   /Users/mihail/Sites/magazin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php
>   on line 77 and defined in
>   /Users/mihail/Sites/magazin/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Controller/ResourceController.php
>   on line 63

Comment: This is a pagination problem ? Maybe you can try to use pagerfanta to do the job ? With the "MaxPerPage" value in your controller

Comment: It is not about pagination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways that you could go with this..

**Controller**

You could extend the controller and pass the variable into your template the same way you could with any other controller.

**Request**

You could just pass the variable to your controller through the GET parameters as the request like your..

```
{{ render(url('sylius_partial_product_latest', {'size': 3, 'limit': 2, 'template': 'SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:latest.html.twig'})) }}
```

.. and then get that in your template using the request object like..

```
{{ grid(product, app.request.get('size')) }} // with a default or null
```

Comment: I described that overriding controller is not easy as it seems. Maybe there some listeners that catch and process some actions or anything else.
But the second method is awesome. I absolutely forget about twig and its access to app-container. Thanks.

Comment: No worries... Although extending the controllers can be quite easy, your error seems to imply that the extended controller doesn't have the `partialAction` method set. Were you extending the base product controller or just adding your own? That being said, I think it would be overkill for your issue.

Comment: `partialAction` exists and I extend base controller. The problem is not so clear... I have a working solution and now overriding is not needed.

Comment: No, not at all. I agree.

Comment: Thank you ! It's bugging me that those are the only solutions. Why would someone create such a system where you, simply put, are a yaml developer but not think about such a simple and common problèm …